# How to create a sales query in SAP Business One

Tags: sapb1

I would like to create a sales query for the past 12 months that can be reapplied once a month.I would like to do the whole thing with the query generator, but I can not find a table from which the sales emerge. I am familiar with the sales analysis, but I would like to simplify the whole thing. Is there a corresponding table at all or is it possible to create one?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly,

are you looking for .ORDR ? this is the sales order header table.
there is also .RDR1 which contains the row data.

if you go to view, then turn on 'system information' table/field details will be displayed in the bottom left.

regards,